# Hindu scriptures before Mahabharata about thinking capability of head

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, history, science

Consider the [following](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09028.htm)  excerpt from the [Shalya Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/index.htm) of [The Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/)

> Indeed, the son of Pandu, filled with rage, struck off that **head which
>   was the root of the evil policy of the Kurus**, with that impetuous
>   shaft winged with gold and whetted on stone. Beholding Shakuni lying
>   headless on the ground and all his limbs drenched with gore, thy
>   warriors, rendered powerless with fear, fled away on all sides with
>   weapons in their hands.

The Sanskrit slokhas corresponding to it are

> 59 sa tacchiro vegavatā śareṇa; suvarṇapuṅkhena **śilāśitena
>        prāverayat kupitaḥ pāṇḍuputro; yat tat kurūṇām anayasya mūlam**
>
> 60 hṛtottamāṅgaṃ śakuniṃ samīkṣya; bhūmau śayānaṃ rudhirārdragātram
>        yodhās tvadīyā bhayanaṣṭa sattvā; diśaḥ prajagmuḥ pragṛhītaśastrāḥ

The bolded portion is interesting to me. The portion is clearly and explicitly stating that the **head** of Shakuni was the **root** of the evil **policy** of the Kurus. It is well known that Shakuni has capability of controlling dies and he has bad behavior from childhood.

From the statement it can be inferred that **head has the capability of thinking**. Since the implicit meaning of the portion is the thoughts of Shakuni is reason for evil policies of Kurus.

So it can be inferred that head as a part of human body that has capability of thinking is known to people during Mahabharata times (atleast to Vyasa).

In this context my doubt is: Are there any Hindu scriptures *earlier*(historically) to  Mahabharata contains either implicitly or explicitly the fact **head has the capability of thinking**.

Note: Since I dont know the actual Sanskrit words, I am analyzing with the above translation only.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101079/discussion-on-question-by-hanugm-hindu-scriptures-before-mahabharata-about-think).

Answer (score 1):

The question is

> Are there any Hindu scriptures earlier(historically) to Mahabharata
>   contains either implicitly or explicitly the fact **head has the
>   capability of thinking.**

---

I don't know why this passage was inferred this way - **the son of Pandu, filled with rage, struck off that head which was the root of the evil policy of the Kurus,**.

It should have been translated as ***the son of Pandu, filled with rage, struck off that head of Sakuni, who was the root of the evil policy of the Kurus,*** as a head cannot be independent of a human body and does whatever it wants to.

It is the mind  that uses the body in doing things, be it good or evil.

---

Sri Krishna says

> तानि सर्वाणि संयम्य युक्त आसीत मत्परः।
>
> वशे हि यस्येन्द्रियाणि तस्य प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठिता।।2.61।।
>
> Restraining them (the same-organs) ***by mind***, the master of Yoga
>   would sit making Me his goal; for, the intellect of that person is
>   stabilized whose sense-organs are under control.

---

Coming to the question part, I would like to say that similar statement appears in Ramayana.  This statement was made by wailing demon women, after the death of Indrajit and many other demons.

> रावणस्यापनीतेन दुर्विनीतस्य दुर्मतेः || ९४-६-३७ अयं निष्टानको घोरः
>   शोकेन समभिप्लुतः |
>
> "As a result of the bad behaviour of Ravana, the wicked demon with an
>   evil disposition of mind, this terrific havoc with grief occurred."